# NetworkStream.CanRead returns true but the buffer returns no value

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ip, networkstream

I have a do while loop that reads a buffer from a `NetworkStream` object
the while condition is `networkStream.CanRead` so as long as it can read, it should continue reading from the buffer. Only problem is when I read from the buffer and convert to string, there is nothing in it. i.e. its empty.

Why would that happen?

This is an ASP.NET(VS2005) application

@dtb Code Info:

I am passing the a `NetworkStream` object `networkStream`

```
// between 2 functions in a loop
{
    SendMessage(networkStream, message);

    ReadMessage(networkStream);
}
```

Funny thing is that if it reconnects and connects again, the Send/ Read works fine. Can it actually be a problem with Send ( I am getting no exceptions here) or reuse of the `NetworkStream` object. This is working fine locally on a test TCP server, but I am getting the above problem when in production (Windows Server 2003) (i.e. can't read anything from the stream -- until I actually time it out (exit the loop) after 10s)

```
ReadMessage(networkStream)
{
    if (networkStream != null && networkStream.CanRead)
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            int numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            string messageRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
            myCompleteMessage.Append(messageRead);
        } while (networkStream.CanRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note: that it does read a message in the first go, after another request of data is sent on the same network stream this happens on the 2nd go

Comment: @soldieraman: If the answer of darkassassin93 does not answer your question, please show us your code. I've got the feeling you're assuming things about packet boundaries and/or the number of bytes returned by the `Read` method that may be wrong.

Comment: So let's see... A stream is a sequence of bytes, it has no concept of a message. So you need something that breaks the stream of bytes into messages. How is a "message" define in your case? Can you give an example? What server are you communicating with? You cannot use `CanRead` to detect the boundary between two messages, and you should not use `DataAvailable` for this.

Answer (score 5):

`CanRead` is a static value that indicates whether or not the stream is *capable* of being read. The [`DataAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librar//system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx) property will let you know if data is ready to read.

Comment: +1. "static value" here means that the value is set once by the constructor and is never changed until the class is disposed (in which case it will be set to `false`)

Comment: There are indications in comments in other questions on SO that CanRead (and CanWrite too I suppose) can be changed, and it happens when the stream is closed. Nevertheless, you are basically right.